# SQL Server : group rows with same value and another row

Tags: sql-server

I have the output of a query like this

```
    Acct#     OwnerType TotalBal   Type1Bal   Type2Bal Type3Bal
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    1234      Type1     0           1000           0        
    1234      Type2     0              0        1000
    1234      Type3     0              0           0      1000
    123456    Type1     0           2000           0         0 
    123456    Type2     0              0        2000         0
    123456    Type3     0              0           0      2000
```

This is the sample data produced by a query.  For each Account Number, I need a header row (something like this), row with total balance with the actually just one of the three balances) . Can anyone suggest or point me in the correct direction?

```
   Acct#     OwnerType TotalBal   Type1Bal   Type2Bal Type3Bal
   -------------------------------------------------------------------
   1234      TotalAmt  1000          0            0       0
   1234      Type1        0       1000            0       0
   1234      Type2        0          0         1000       0
   1234      Type3        0          0            0    1000
   123456    TotalAmt  2000          0            0       0
   123456    Type1        0       2000            0       0 
   123456    Type2        0          0         2000       0
   123456    Type3        0          0            0    2000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Declare @Table table (Acct int,OwnerType varchar(25),TotalBal int,Type1Bal int,Type2Bal int,Type3Bal int)
Insert into @Table values
(1234      ,'Type1',     0,          1000,         0 ,       null),
(1234      ,'Type2',     0 ,          0   ,        1000,     null),
(1234      ,'Type3',     0 ,          0   ,         0 ,        1000),
(123456    ,'Type1',     0 ,          2000 ,        0  ,        0 ),
(123456    ,'Type2',     0 ,          0    ,       2000 ,       0),
(123456    ,'Type3',     0 ,           0   ,         0  ,       2000)


Select Acct,OwnerType='TotalAmt',TotalBal=max(Type1Bal),Type1Bal=0,Type2Bal=0,Type3Bal=0 From @Table Group By Acct
Union All
Select Acct,OwnerType,TotalBal=0,Type1Bal=isnull(Type1Bal,0),isnull(Type2Bal,0),IsNull(Type3Bal,0) from @Table
 Order By Acct,OwnerType
```

Returns

```
Acct    OwnerType   TotalBal    Type1Bal    Type2Bal    Type3Bal
1234    TotalAmt    1000        0           0           0
1234    Type1       0           1000        0           0
1234    Type2       0           0           1000        0
1234    Type3       0           0           0           1000
123456  TotalAmt    2000        0           0           0
123456  Type1       0           2000        0           0
123456  Type2       0           0           2000        0
123456  Type3       0           0           0           2000
```